# What is this kind of initialization in Python called?

Tags: python

I came across a similar code as below

```
_name: "Test" = None
```

I am new to python and trying to understand the above initialization method. If use the variable _name before assigning it to something else the output is None.

[image]

Wondering the use of assigning it to "Test" in the first place. I googled it but could not find any reference.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: That's a *type annotation* - and a bad one at that, as `None` is not a value of type `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the syntax that is used for assigning types to variables,

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html here’s the documentation.

Yours is a bad example. It’s usually used in functions.